# Adding a tool tip popup within ordering table header cell

Tags: html, css

Sorry in advance as I'm new to coding more complex kind of features for a website.

I'm trying to add a tool tip popup within one of the header cells in order to provide more information to the user.

I have the components needed so to speak, just having issues integrating / merging the existing table code with tool tip function.

HTML:

```
<div>
 <table id="lst-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Model <br>Ref.</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Perf <br>Type</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">LST Cover <br>Length</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">LST Cover <br>Colour</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Mounting <br>Type</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">TRV <br>Aperature</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Healthcare</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Sloped <br>Top</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Quantity</th>
     <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Order <br>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
</div>  




<br><br><div class="tooltip-lst">ⓘ
  <span class="tooltiptext">Is an aperature required to accommodate a   Thermostatic Radiator Valve (TRV). TRV supplied by others.</span></div>
```

CSS (tool tip css code is final three paragraphs):

```
.lst-table{
text-align: right;
position: relative;
border-collapse: collapse;
background-color: #7F7753;
}
.lst-td, th {
border: 1px solid #999;
padding: 10px;
}
.lst-th {
background: #7F7753;
color: white;
border-radius: 0;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
padding: 10px;
}
.lst-input-ral-box {
border: 1px solid #d7d6d6;
display: flex;
gap: 0;
width:85px;
}
.lst-input-ral-box:focus-within {
border: 0px solid #000;
}
input {
border: none;
outline: none;
}
.tooltip-lst {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip-lst .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
  
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
  
.tooltip-lst:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the popup within the relevant th (which I assume here is the one with text TRV).

However, you also need to make sure that when it is showing it goes in front of neighbouring ths, otherwise part of it will be covered.

This snippet sets the z-index of the th element when hovered to make this possible.

```html
<style>
  .lst-table {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #7F7753;
  }
  
  .lst-td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .lst-th {
    background: #7F7753;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .lst-input-ral-box {
    border: 1px solid #d7d6d6;
    display: flex;
    gap: 0;
    width: 85px;
  }
  
  .lst-input-ral-box:focus-within {
    border: 0px solid #000;
  }
  
  input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .tooltip-lst {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .tooltip-lst .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .lst-th:hover {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .tooltip-lst:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <table id="lst-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Model <br>Ref.</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Perf <br>Type</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">LST Cover <br>Length</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">LST Cover <br>Colour</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Mounting <br>Type</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">TRV <br>Aperature
          <br><br>
          <div class="tooltip-lst">ⓘ
            <span class="tooltiptext">Is an aperature required to accommodate a   Thermostatic Radiator Valve (TRV). TRV supplied by others.</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Healthcare</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Sloped <br>Top</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Quantity</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Order <br>Code</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide the solution to my problem, worked like a charm.